# Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'. in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Launching lib\main.dart on RMX2061 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Parameter format not correct -

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Failed to transform artifact 'x86_debug.jar (io.flutter:x86_debug:1.0.0-c8e3b9485386425213e2973126d6f57e7ed83c54)' to match attributes {artifactType=android-classes, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for IdentityTransform: C:\Users\manoj sirrupu.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.flutter\x86_debug\1.0.0-c8e3b9485386425213e2973126d6f57e7ed83c54\570a59b7be41f73458509975d3eefca7ad5561cf\x86_debug-1.0.0-c8e3b9485386425213e2973126d6f57e7ed83c54.jar.
> > Cannot parse result path string:

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3m 12s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue on flutter:

> Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
>
> [Screenshot of error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWUYA.png)

Solution:
Changed the company domain with only one dot.
[Screenshot with example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8OqF.png)